# CSS dropdown menu does not work when mouse is over two overlapping canvases

Tags: css, html, canvas, drop-down-menu, onmouseover

I am not sure if the title of the question is clear, but here is a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8WTCJ/) of the problem.
When the the dropdown menu is expanded and mouse is taken to the lower items the menu colapses since the submenu is on top f the over lapping canvas.

The interesting part is if I remove the second canvas the menu works fine.

```
<canvas width=500 height=500 id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas width=500 height=500 id="canvas2" style="position: relative; top:-500px"></canvas>
```

I also tried to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9UJS/1/) using jqueryui but ther also it does not work as expected.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you un-comment the part inside `/* Bring the nav above everything else--uncomment if needed.` it works just fine, which means adding

```
position:relative;
z-index:5;
```

to `#nav`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8WTCJ/1/)

Comment: This is cool, was it because the second canvas was on top of the menu also?

Comment: @ThankYouSRT Yes, the canvas was overlaying the menu because it was further down in the HTML chain

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ready-to-use solution, based on CSS and Canvas?
A menu builder like Swimbi - http://f-source.com/swimbi/
and 
[Chrome version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swimbi-html5css-menu-make/oifipbbfaomegkfhpdbopinkndcdmaop)